# Special symbols in wordpress search

Tags: php, search, wordpress, html-encode

I try create search it based on custom search but i have one bug `&amp;` symbol, when i save my post near text like  `SDG&E` wordpress add this `SDG&amp;E`

Anyone have any idias how search `SDG&E` when in post it is `SDG&amp;E`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Also, encoding html characters is not a "bug," it's a security measure.

Comment: when i try search with this term `SDG&E` i haven't any result

Comment: Could modify `_POST` and do `$_POST['search'] = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $_POST['search']);` before wordpress does the search

Comment: @Adam thanks it's works!!!

Comment: Oh sweet I'll post it as an answer then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try modifying the `_POST` data that is sent before wordpress performs the search, for example

```
$_POST['search'] = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $_POST['search']);
```

Then you can do the reverse when displaying what the search term actually was.